# JBOSS EAP 6.4.0 not accepting external requests

Tags: jboss-eap-6

This seems like a simple question and I'm sorry to ask it.

My JBOSS application (EAP-6.4.0) isn't accepting external requests.

I've tried 'standalone.sh -b 192.168.1.12' to start it and I've tried modifying the
interface declaration in standalone.xml to be like this:

```
<interface name="public">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.1.12}"/>
</interface>
```

and this:

```
<interface name="public">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
</interface>
```

Neither of the above attempts allow a request from a different computer.
I can however pull up the application from the same computer.

Is there something else I should be doing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running on CentOS 8.4 and CentOS has a firewall enabled by default.

Turning it completely off allowed my jboss to answer external requests:

`systemctl stop firewalld`

So I turned the firewall back on, then enabled port 8080 to pass through:

`systemctl start firewalld`

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp`

`firewall-cmd —reload`

After all this my external requests are still being serviced. Yay.